# How do you say 'He said that he went there' in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, translation

Konnichiwa.

Just a beginner here ; how do you say that sort of sentence wherein it involves a that-phrase that follows a verb?

Arigatou !

Comment: Whenever you ask for help in a sentence, it'd be good if you posted your attempt on the sentence beforehand, so we can understand where you're having trouble. Sometimes questions without your own attempt, will be classfied as off topic.

Comment: Welcome to JLSE!  This website is designed to facilitate learning.  To increase the opportunity for learning, we request that in your questions you include your attempts to use the language.

Answer (score 3):

As a possible translation:

> 彼は「彼がそこに行った」と言った
>   (Kare wa kare ga soko ni itta to itta)

Notice the brackets; there are particular brackets you can use for speech specifically which can denote a phrase such as you highlighted.

The "to itta" is "he said". You could substitute this with something else.

"kare ga soko ni itta" is the action that the person supposedly did - "he went over there".

This can also be cut down further assuming the context is known (for example we both know who "he" is and its obvious we are refering to him) to:

> 「彼がそこに行った」と言った
>   (kare ga soko ni itta to itta)

Comment: This answer is good but, depending on the context, I would omit 「彼が」 since 「彼は彼が」 sounds a little wordy.

Comment: 「彼は『彼がそこに行った』と言った」 would mean "He said 'He went there.'" rather than "He said 'I went there.'" = "He said that he went there", no? 「『彼がそこに行った』と言った」 would mean "(I/Someone) said 'He went there.'" = (I/Someone other than him) said that he went there", no?